# Where Can I Find the 'Available On The App Store' Logo?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I think Apple provides hi-res logos to "Available on the App Store" in the iOS  developer center, but I couldn't find it. Can anyone please direct me to a link to this?

Note: I am looking for the official logo selections, not "johnny's site has a link over here."

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The logo you want is available [at this link](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/marketing/guidelines/#downloadOnAppstore).

Comment: meh? I only see a blank screen there (and yes, I've logged in)

Comment: Sorry 'bout that...Fixed link.

Comment: By the way, Developer Login is not required now

Comment: Here is the equivalent for Google Play: https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/badges/

Answer (score 7):

[Another official link](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/marketing/guidelines/#downloadOnAppstore) with PNG, Print EPS, and Retina SVGs that doesn't require dev login

Comment: According to the Apple guidelines, you can only use images provided in the download and that includes an EPS for print and an SVG for digital. Note that there is no PNG image, so this format should not be used to comply with their rules.

Comment: god damn why they have to be so difficult always and not support png

Answer (score 1):

Official [Available on the App Store logo](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/marketing/guidelines/#downloadOnAppstore), from developer.apple.com.  Doesn't require Dev login